# Need a SQL Query to string trim from data in 1 table and match to another

Tags: sql

OK so here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Table 1 has a column called inifile, path.  Entries look like...

```
----------------------------------
|   inifile   |     path          | 
----------------------------------
|example1.ini | c:\temp\text.txt  |
|example2.ini | c:\temp\text2.txt |
----------------------------------
```

Table 2 has columns called jobs, and job name.  Entries look like...

```
---------------------------- 
|  jobs    |   job name    |
----------------------------
| example1 | Example Job 1 |
| example2 | Example Job 2 |
----------------------------
```

The jobs data in Table 2 matches the inifile from Table 1, minus the '.ini' extension.  So I need to trim the extension off of the 'inifile' field, and join it with the 'jobs' field, to return the 'job name' and 'path'.  The field lengths in the inifile are varying in length.

So the return brings back

```
------------------------------------------------------
|  jobs     |    job name         |   path           |
------------------------------------------------------
| example1  |  Example Job 1      | c:\temp\text.txt |
| example2  |  Example Job 2      | c:\temp\text2.txt|
------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm wracking my brain over this and haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Table2.jobs, table2.JobName, table1.Path
FROM
  Table1
  JOIN Table2 ON table2.jobs = REPLACE(table1.inifile, '.ini','')
```

Comment: This presumes that there will only be one occurrence of the string ".ini", at the end of the inifile.  The `REPLACE ` function in this example would remove *all* occurrences of the string ".ini". That is, if inifile contains the value "foo.init.conf.ini", the function would return "foot.conf". This answers the question that was asked. Personally, rather than removing ".ini" from inifile, I'd prefer to append '.ini' to table2.jobs, and do the comparison... **`CONCAT(table2.jobs,'.ini') = table1.inifile`**  (CONCAT is for MySQL. Other database use different functions/operators for string concat.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it for you:

```
Select T2.* 
  from T2
    inner join T1 on Replace(inifile, '.ini', '') = T2.jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT Table2.jobs, Table2.JobName, table1.Path
    FROM 
     (select REPLACE(inifile, '.ini','') jobs ,path  
      from Table1 ) table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
    ON Table2.jobs = table1.jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are guaranteed that there is at most one occurrence of '.ini' within the string value, and that it's at the end of the string, then the `REPLACE` function (demonstrated in other answers) can work for you.

To trim the string at the first occurrence of '.ini', you could use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function

```
 SET @foo = 'foo.ini' ;
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@foo,'.ini',1) ;
```

If there's a possibility of multiple occurrences of '.ini' within the string, and your goal is to remove '.ini' from the end of the string...

```
 SET @foo = 'foo.init.bar.ini'; 
 SELECT IF(@foo LIKE '%.ini',SUBSTRING(@foo,1,CHAR_LENGTH(@foo)-4),@foo) ;
```

Whichever expression does what you need it to do to return the value in your column, you can use that expression in a predicate.

```
SELECT ...
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.jobs = IF(t1.inifile LIKE %.ini'
                   ,SUBSTRING(t1.inifile,1,CHAR_LENGTH(t1.initfile)-4)
                   ,t1.inifile
                 )
```

As an alternative, you might consider just concatenating `".ini"` to the value of the column in table2, and doing the comparison

```
    ON CONCAT(t2.jobs,'.ini') = t1.inifile
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify RDBMS. Assuming that you are using `SQL Server 2012+` you could use [`PARSENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx):

```
SELECT t2.job, t2.job_name, t1.path
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON PARSENAME(inifile,2) = t2.job;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/452223)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║   job    ║   job_name    ║       path       ║
╠══════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ example1 ║ Example Job 1 ║ c:\temp\text.txt ║
║ example2 ║ Example Job 2 ║ c:\temp\text2.tx ║
╚══════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```